# Putting Oracle DLLs in a sub folder for a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I thought this would be simple but maybe its me!!!

I have a web application and deploy to various servers. I have had issues with other development teams upgrading Oracle etc so I decided to copy the Oracle Drivers I need into a sub folder called Lib.

So what I what to do is have my my Dll's in Bin, that reference the Oracle Dll's... load them from the Lib sub folder... Bin\Lib

The main Oracle Dll is the Oracle.DataAccess.dll and I have the OCI.dll etc all in the same folder.

I tried adding the section

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

but it failed to load the Dll.

I dont want to use reflection or anything that dynamically loads them, I dont want to set the path or use the GAC. I simply want my Dll to access the Oracle Dll's in the Lib folder.

I have a few Projects that compile into DLL's that are part of my web site.

Has anyone got a clue on this as I've tried most of this. I used to thing that the CLR would search the main directory first and then sub directories but this doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: In Visual Studio, just find the DLL under *References* and set the `Copy Local` property to *True*.  That's really all you should need to do.

Comment: @Mike - I tried that Mike... what that does is copy the reference to the Oracle.DataAccess.Dll located in my sub folder 'lib' to the bin directory. I want to keep this in the Lib folder with the other Oracle Dll's :-(  - thanks again

Comment: Oh yea.  I think you can muck with the DLL resolution but I'm not sure how.  I've never had the need to do that.

Comment: in my Project file I have the following in the ItemGroup..   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>lib\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

Comment: Maybe you need to fully qualify the path?  Or at least add the `bin\lib` in there?

Comment: @Mike.. yes Mike that might work but my FQP would be different on different environments so I was looking to use a relative path

Comment: Well, fully qualify the path and if that works, at least you'll know your technique works.  Then, you can figure out where the path is relative to and adjust it accordingly.